# Demonstrate that the centering matrix is idempotent

Tags: matrices, idempotents

I want to demonstrate that the [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) $H$ is idempotent (i.e. $HH=H$). The centering matrix is defined as $H=I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T$.

I've tried developing this:
$$
HH=\\
H(I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T)= \\
HI-H\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T=\\
I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T-(I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T)\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T= \\
I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T+\frac{1}{n^2}1\, 1^T
$$

From here, I should obtain again the original form $I-\frac{1}{n}1\, 1^T$, but I don't know how. Any ideas on how to proceed? Or any ideas on a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third line you have $HI - H \frac{1}{n} 11^T$. So the assertion follows if $H \frac{1}{n} 11^T = 0$. Now substitute again for $H$, you'll see that the assertion follows if $11^T = \frac{1}{n} 11^T 11^T$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $11^T 11^T = n 11^T$ so the assertion follows.

To see why $11^T 11^T = n 11^T$ note that $11^T_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \times 1$.